# Magento 2 query builder conditional order by

Tags: database, query

I have this query builder, which works fine.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    'sales_order_item',
    'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
    array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)'));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    'catalog_category_product',
    'e.entity_id = catalog_category_product.entity_id',
    array('product_position'=>'catalog_category_product.position'))
    ->group('e.entity_id')
    ->order('product_position ASC','qty_ordered DESC');
```

However, I would like to have a **conditional order by** as I could in a raw mysql. I'd like the order by to be like this,

```
CASE product_position WHEN <> 0 THEN product_position ELSE qty_ordered END ASC
```

How can I convert the above query to Magento query builder?